# Arduino: How to resolve problem with timer not showing numbers properly on a 4-digit 7-segment display?

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

**What the code does:**

1. The code starts off by showing a short "blinking animation", where segments A-F turns on and off one at a time.
2. The "blinking animation" lasts between 3-10 seconds, upon which a timer starts.
3. The timer counts from 0-99 seconds using Digit 1 & 2, while Digit 3 & 4 shows 100th and 10th, respectively, of a second (sorry for bad usage of the unit in english! Basicly = 100 ms and 10 ms).
4. By using the connected button, you can stop the timer by pressing it. Timer stops and shows the time.

> 

**My problem:**
the problem I'm facing is that after the blinking animation ends and the timer starts, the display won't show individual numbers in digit 2 & 3, instead there's a mishmash of numbers lit while the timer counts. However, I did notice that basically whatever number is displayed in Digit 1, will be shown simultanously in the background in Digit 2 & 3 as well. So for example:

1. Timer: 01.XX-09.XX =>> a zero is seen in the background of digit 2 & 3, while timer is counting.
2. Timer: 10.XX-19.XX =>> a one is seen in the background of digit 2 & 3, while timer is counting.
3. Timer: 20.XX-29.XX =>> a two is seen in the background of digit 2 & 3, while timer is counting etc.

> 

**The wiring:** (DP-segment has intensionally been left out.)

```
SEGMENT-A = Arduino Pin 11
SEGMENT-B = Arduino Pin 7
SEGMENT-C = Arduino Pin 4
SEGMENT-D = Arduino Pin 2
SEGMENT-E = Arduino Pin 13
SEGMENT-F = Arduino Pin 10
SEGMENT-G = Arduino Pin 5
```

[image]

> 

**Here's the code:** done in C-language using PlatformIO. Followed what seems to be a basic code for Arduino Uno, when creating a timer with a 4 digit 7 segment display.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define PORTB_ON PORTB = 255;
#define PORTD_ON PORTD = 255;
#define PORTB_OFF PORTB = 0;
#define PORTD_OFF PORTD = 0;

//SEGEMENTS ON
#define SEGMENT_A_ON PORTB = PORTB | 1 << PB3; //SEGMENT-A light on      (Arduino Pin 11)
#define SEGMENT_B_ON PORTD = PORTD | 1 << PD7; //SEGMENT-B light on      (Arduino Pin  7)
#define SEGMENT_C_ON PORTD = PORTD | 1 << PD4; //SEGMENT-C light on      (Arduino Pin  4)
#define SEGMENT_D_ON PORTD = PORTD | 1 << PD2; //SEGMENT-D light on      (Arduino Pin  2)
#define SEGMENT_E_ON PORTB = PORTB | 1 << PB5; //SEGMENT-E light on      (Arduino Pin  13)
#define SEGMENT_F_ON PORTB = PORTB | 1 << PB2; //SEGMENT-F light on      (Arduino Pin  10)
#define SEGMENT_G_ON PORTD = PORTD | 1 << PD5; //SEGMENT-G light on      (Arduino Pin  5)
//SEGMENTS OFF
#define SEGMENT_A_OFF PORTB = PORTB & ~1 << PB3; //SEGMENT-A light off      (Arduino Pin  11)
#define SEGMENT_B_OFF PORTD = PORTD & ~1 << PD7; //SEGMENT-B light off      (Arduino Pin  7)
#define SEGMENT_C_OFF PORTD = PORTD & ~1 << PD4; //SEGMENT-C light off      (Arduino Pin  4)
#define SEGMENT_D_OFF PORTD = PORTD & ~1 << PD2; //SEGMENT-D light off      (Arduino Pin  2)
#define SEGMENT_E_OFF PORTB = PORTB & ~1 << PB5; //SEGMENT-E light off      (Arduino Pin  13)
#define SEGMENT_F_OFF PORTB = PORTB & ~1 << PB2; //SEGMENT-F light off      (Arduino Pin  10)
#define SEGMENT_G_OFF PORTD = PORTD & ~1 << PD5; //SEGMENT-G light off      (Arduino Pin  5)


//DIGITS ON = Display , 2, 3 & 4
#define DIGIT_1_ON PORTB = PORTB & ~1 << PB4; //DISPLAY 1 off      (Arduino Pin  12)
#define DIGIT_2_ON PORTB = PORTB & ~1 << PB1; //DISPLAY 2 off      (Arduino Pin  9)
#define DIGIT_3_ON PORTB = PORTB & ~1 << PB0; //DISPLAY 3 off      (Arduino Pin  8)
#define DIGIT_4_ON PORTD = PORTD & ~1 << PD6; //DISPLAY 4 off      (Arduino Pin  6)
//DIGITS OFF = Display: 1, 2, 3 & 4
#define DIGIT_1_OFF PORTB = PORTB | 1 << PB4; //DISPLAY 1 on      (Arduino Pin  12)
#define DIGIT_2_OFF PORTB = PORTB | 1 << PB1; //DISPLAY 2 on      (Arduino Pin  9)
#define DIGIT_3_OFF PORTB = PORTB | 1 << PB0; //DISPLAY 3 on      (Arduino Pin  8)
#define DIGIT_4_OFF PORTD = PORTD | 1 << PD6; //DISPLAY 4 on      (Arduino Pin  6)


void startDisplay();
void stopDisplay();
void choseDigit(int x);
void showNumberOnDisplay(int x);
void blinkingAnimation();
void zero();
void one();
void two();
void three();
void four();
void five();
void six();
void seven();
void eight();
void nine();

int x = 100;
long number = 0;
int recentTime;
int digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4;
int stopButton;

int main()
{
  DDRB = 255;
  DDRD = 0b11011111;
  srand(time(NULL));

  while (1)
  {
    if (number == 0)
    {
      int randomWaitTime = rand() % 10 + 3; //Calls random number between 3-10
      for (int i = 0; i < randomWaitTime; i++)
      {
        blinkingAnimation();
      }
    }
    startDisplay();

    if (PIND & 1 << PD3)
    {
      stopButton = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      stopButton = 1;
    }

    if (stopButton == 0)
    {
      stopDisplay();
    }
  }
    
  return 0;
}

void startDisplay()
{
  turnAllSegmentsOff();                 //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(1);                        //Turn Display 1 on
  showNumberOnDisplay((number / 1000)); //Get value of thousand
  _delay_ms(2.5);                       //Delay 2.5ms

  turnAllSegmentsOff();                       //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(2);                              //Turn Display 2 on
  showNumberOnDisplay((number % 1000) / 100); //Get value of hundred
  _delay_ms(2.5);                             //Delay 2.5ms

  turnAllSegmentsOff();                   //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(3);                          //Turn Display 3 on
  showNumberOnDisplay(number % 100 / 10); //Get value of ten
  _delay_ms(2.5);                         //Delay 2.5ms

  turnAllSegmentsOff();             //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(4);                    //Turn Display 3 on
  showNumberOnDisplay(number % 10); //Get value of single digit
  _delay_ms(2.5);                   //Delay 2.5ms

  number++;
  if (number == 9999) // Reset number count to 1;
  {
    number = 1;
  }
}

void stopDisplay()
{
  recentTime = number;
  digit1 = recentTime / 1000;
  digit2 = (recentTime % 1000) / 100;
  digit3 = recentTime % 100 / 10;
  digit4 = recentTime % 10;

  while (stopButton == 0)
  {
    turnAllSegmentsOff();        //Turn ALL segments off
    choseDigit(1);               //Turn Display 1 on
    showNumberOnDisplay(digit1); //Get value of thousand
    _delay_ms(2.5);              //Delay 2.5ms

    turnAllSegmentsOff();        //Turn ALL segments off
    choseDigit(2);               //Turn Display 2 on
    showNumberOnDisplay(digit2); //Get value of hundred
    _delay_ms(2.5);              //Delay 2.5ms

    turnAllSegmentsOff();        //Turn ALL segments off
    choseDigit(3);               //Turn Display 3 on
    showNumberOnDisplay(digit3); //Get value of ten
    _delay_ms(2.5);              //Delay 2.5ms

    turnAllSegmentsOff();        //Turn ALL segments off
    choseDigit(4);               //Turn Display 3 on
    showNumberOnDisplay(digit4); //Get value of single digit
    _delay_ms(2.5);              //Delay 2.5ms
  }
}

void choseDigit(int x)
{
  DIGIT_1_OFF
  DIGIT_2_OFF
  DIGIT_3_OFF
  DIGIT_4_OFF
  switch (x)
  {
  case 1:
    DIGIT_1_ON //Display 1 on
        break;
  case 2:
    DIGIT_2_ON //Display 2 on
        break;
  case 3:
    DIGIT_3_ON //Display 3 on
        break;
  case 4:
    DIGIT_4_ON //Display 4 on
        break;
  }
}

void showNumberOnDisplay(int x)
{
  switch (x)
  {
  case 1:
    one();
    break;

  case 2:
    two();
    break;

  case 3:
    three();
    break;

  case 4:
    four();
    break;

  case 5:
    five();
    break;

  case 6:
    six();
    break;

  case 7:
    seven();
    break;

  case 8:
    eight();
    break;

  case 9:
    nine();
    break;

  default:
    zero();
    break;
  }
}

void blinkingAnimation()
{
  DIGIT_1_ON
  DIGIT_2_ON
  DIGIT_3_ON
  DIGIT_4_ON
  SEGMENT_B_OFF
  SEGMENT_E_ON;
  _delay_ms(165);
  SEGMENT_E_OFF;
  SEGMENT_D_ON
  _delay_ms(165);
  SEGMENT_D_OFF
  SEGMENT_C_ON
  _delay_ms(165);
  SEGMENT_C_OFF
  SEGMENT_B_ON
  _delay_ms(165);
  SEGMENT_B_OFF
  SEGMENT_A_ON
  _delay_ms(165);
  SEGMENT_A_OFF
  SEGMENT_F_ON
  _delay_ms(165);
  SEGMENT_F_OFF
}

void turnAllSegmentsOff()
{
  PORTB_OFF
  PORTD_OFF
}

//Display number 0
void zero()
{
  SEGMENT_A_ON;
  SEGMENT_B_ON;
  SEGMENT_C_ON;
  SEGMENT_D_ON;
  SEGMENT_E_ON;
  SEGMENT_F_ON;
}

//DISPLAY number 1
void one()
{
  SEGMENT_B_ON;
  SEGMENT_C_ON;
}

//DISPLAY number 2
void two()
{
  SEGMENT_A_ON;
  SEGMENT_B_ON;
  SEGMENT_G_ON;
  SEGMENT_E_ON;
  SEGMENT_D_ON;
}

//DISPLAY number 3
void three()
{
  SEGMENT_A_ON;
  SEGMENT_B_ON;
  SEGMENT_G_ON;
  SEGMENT_C_ON;
  SEGMENT_D_ON;
}

//DISPLAY number 4
void four()
{
  SEGMENT_F_ON;
  SEGMENT_G_ON;
  SEGMENT_B_ON;
  SEGMENT_C_ON;
}

//DISPLAY number 5
void five()
{
  SEGMENT_A_ON;
  SEGMENT_F_ON;
  SEGMENT_G_ON;
  SEGMENT_C_ON;
  SEGMENT_D_ON;
}

//DISPLAY number 6
void six()
{
  SEGMENT_A_ON;
  SEGMENT_F_ON;
  SEGMENT_E_ON;
  SEGMENT_D_ON;
  SEGMENT_C_ON;
  SEGMENT_G_ON;
}

//DISPLAY number 7
void seven()
{
  SEGMENT_A_ON;
  SEGMENT_B_ON;
  SEGMENT_C_ON;
}

//DISPLAY number 8
void eight()
{
  SEGMENT_A_ON;
  SEGMENT_B_ON;
  SEGMENT_C_ON;
  SEGMENT_D_ON;
  SEGMENT_E_ON;
  SEGMENT_F_ON;
  SEGMENT_G_ON;
}

//DISPLAY number 9
void nine()
{
  SEGMENT_A_ON;
  SEGMENT_F_ON;
  SEGMENT_G_ON;
  SEGMENT_B_ON;
  SEGMENT_C_ON;
  SEGMENT_D_ON;
}
```

Comment: Two observations a) `main()` has unmatched `{` braces `}` and b) you never call function `stopDisplay()`.

Comment: Hmm...ow! I'll have a look at it, probably just a silly miss while cleaning up the code. Wanted to keep only the stuff that mattered here for my problem, while keeping things neat and removing any distractions.

Comment: There is a lot of unnecessary description, it isn't very clear what works, and what does not.

Comment: I edited the Question. Added the "stopDisplay" part in the code and fixed the braces. Everything that I posted in "what the code does" works. Just that when the numbers are displayed on the screen, it won't show them properly. The problem have been explained more in detail under the "problem" section.

Comment: You seem to be turning all segments off, for every digit, then only enabling one of them, and delaying. Also, in `choseDigit()` you seem to turn them all on, and then turn one off, although the comment says the opposite `DIGIT_1_OFF //Display 1 on`. The digits with the worst visibility are those whose value changes the most often. How clear do you think a digit changing at 1/100th second will look? But I don't really follow the logic. I don't get why you don't write all 4 digits in succession. Note too, if you keep enabling and disabling you'll get flickering.

Comment: Terrible implementation.  Figure out what the 7-bit number is for each digit based on your pin assignments and just assign it.   Silly macros and delays just make it less reliable.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I apologize for the confusion and should have known better than to keep my comment there. It's just that with 4 digit 7 segment display the process is reversed for digits compared to the segments. This means that implementing following code for example: `PORTB = PORTB & ~1 << PB4;`, it would normally turn off something. While `PORTB = PORTB | 1 << PB4;` would turn something on. Again bad comment. I'm new to this and learning, that's why I'm asking for help. Appreciate any suggestions or if you know a website you could recommend/direct me to for this particular problem.

Comment: Take a fresh look at what you are doing after this attempt. See what TomServo said. You've got the segments on different ports and that makes it hard work. 8 segments ==> 8 bits ==> one port. Then you can start with an `array[10]` of segment patterns for each digit, and just write the correct pattern to the port. By turning segments on and off individually you'll inevitably get flicker. So now, you won't need to turn a segment off: just write the new segment pattern. Get rid of the macros, and the seperate functions for each digit. Example: `PORTD = array[7];` done in one line.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I've been reading...and reading...and reading...and reading your post several times. I finally think I know what you mean. Tomorrow when I get home from work, I'll spend a few hours re-wiring and coding and get back to you to see if I got it right. Much appreciation for your guidance Vane & Tom.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Your suggestion was neat and great! Removed and cleaned the code by making an array for the segment patterns (0-9): `int segmentNumberArray[10] = {0B01111110, 0B00001100, 0B010110110, 0B10011110, 0B011001100, 0B11011010, 0B11111010, 0B00001110, 0B11111110, 0B11011110};`, by putting all segments on PORTD. Further put digit (1-4) on PORTB and did an array: `int digitArray[4] = {0B00000100, 0B00001000, 0B00010000, 0B00100000};`. So far so good! Now I'm stuck getting a working timer. I do manage to get the right ms on each digit, but the switching between digits is my problem.